# Problema / Duda con Spring Security y Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

Buen día, estoy trabajando con Spring Boot 1.4.2.RELEASE, Spring Security 4.1.3.RELEASE, y Java 8.

Para la configuración de seguridad tengo la siguiente clase:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/assets/**", "/logout", "/login");
    }
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .sessionManagement()  // Comentando estas líneas funciona: 1
                    .sessionFixation() // 2
                    .migrateSession() // 3
                    .maximumSessions(1) // 4
                    .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true).expiredUrl("/login").and() 
                    .invalidSessionUrl("/login") // 5
                    .and() // 6
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/app/**").authenticated()
                    .antMatchers("/about").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                    .loginProcessingUrl("/auth").permitAll()
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/app/index", true)
                    .failureUrl("/login?error")
                    .usernameParameter("uid")
                    .passwordParameter("pwd").and()
                .logout()
                    .permitAll()
                    .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                    .logoutUrl("/logout").permitAll()
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/login").permitAll()
                    .clearAuthentication(true).and()
                .exceptionHandling().and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .headers().frameOptions().disable()
                .cacheControl().and();
    }
}
```

El problema es que cuando trato de acceder a "/about", al haberla configurado con "permitAll", esperaría acceder pero la petición me redirige a "/login". Lo intento por segunda vez y ahora me deja acceder sin problemas a "/about".

He cambiado el orden de autorización de peticiones, comentando la línea `anyRequest().authenticated()` y no me ha funcionado, sin embargo, noté que cuando elimino las líneas de sessionManagement (1 al 6), todo funciona normalmente.

¿Me hace falta alguna configuración extra?

Comment: Solucionado, agregué: `sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)` y funcionó de acuerdo a lo esperado.